# 7zip: how to extract to std output?

Tags: 7-zip

I have 7z 4.65 and am trying to extract a single file to standard output. The 7z command-line help says `-so` is the command-line parameter to extract to standard output, but when I try this:

```
>>> 7z e -so dist\dlogpkg.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

7-Zip 4.65  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-02-03
Error:
I won't write data and program's messages to same terminal
```

how can I fix this? There doesn't seem to be a command line param to suppress the normal 7z stdout messages.

(edit: the equivalent operation in "unzip" would be

```
unzip -p dist\dlogpkg.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

which works fine. But I'd like to use 7z for various reasons.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

pipe it to another program such as

- tee
- less
- more

i think `tee` comes closest to what you want, it drops the 7z stuff and just gives you the content.

```
% 7z e -so dist\dlogpkg.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | tee
```

Comment: Is there any reason in particular why you think `tee` is better in this situation than `less`?

Comment: Odd. "less" and "tee" do what I expect, but "more" leaves in the 7z stuff.... bizarre! why does it do this?

Comment: @Andy: "tee" does even less than "less" .. no scrolling back etc. it just lets the bytes through and not a thing more.

Comment: @akira maybe he wanted to pipe the output to another program

Comment: @Andy: why OP wanted to pipe to stdout was never a question.

Comment: @JasonS Because less is more

Answer (score 9):

I was also trying to figure this out. This got me what I wanted:

```
7z x -so my_file.zip 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Windows equivalent `7z x -so my_file.zip 2> NUL` doesn't work: somehow also redirects data to null.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, `7z x -so my_file.zip 2> NUL` doesn't work, but redirection to a real file helps:

```
7z x -so my_file.zip 2> _garbage.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

On Win 10, to avoid 7z stuff on stdout I use option  -bso0
(see 7z help:
-bs{o|e|p}{0|1|2} : set output stream for output/error/progress line
)

to process the 7z output in cmd.exe batch script, working for TEXT files:
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ( `7z e -bso0 -so infile.7z fileToExtract.txt` ) do (
rem process %%a text line
)